# Solve for real numbers. $6x+3y+2z=18,108(x+y+z)^{(x+y+z)}=xy^2z^36^{(x+y+z)}$

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

Solve for real numbers.
$$
\begin{cases}
6x+3y+2z=18 \\
108(x+y+z)^{(x+y+z)}=6^{(x+y+z)}xy^2z^3
\end{cases}
$$

To solve this system of equation by trial and error I found $(x,y,z) = (1,2,3)$. I could not find any other root.

From second equation we see $xz>0$ , we also know $x+y+z>0$. I tried to show there are no other roots, please help me to complete it.

Comment: We have three variables but only two equations . We cannot determine a unique value for $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit, be careful. The equations are not linear so your statement is not really valid. What about the equation $x^2+y^2=0$? Is has two variables on a single equation. However you can determine the unique solution: $x=y=0$.

Comment: can we prove x>0,y>0 ad z>0

Comment: How have you come accross that system? It's quite unusual to see something like that

Comment: From Jalil Hajimir